# PHP Add up a series of minutes:seconds

Tags: php, math, time

I have a list of video segment durations I need to add up to get the total duration.

The series is like this:

- 0:33
- 4:30
- 6:03
- 2:10

...etc

I need to add up the minutes and seconds to get a total video duration.

---

Here's the modified function of my accepted answer:

```
function getTotalDuration ($durations) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($durations as $duration) {
        $duration = explode(':',$duration);
        $total += $duration[0] * 60;
        $total += $duration[1];
    }
    $mins = floor($total / 60);
    $secs = str_pad ( $total % 60, '2', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $mins.':'.$secs;
}
```

Just made sure the output looks correct.

Comment: okay, do it. No seriously, what have you got so far? Any idea how you are goin to do this? It is quite trivial really. You will get more answers here if you show what you've got so far.

Comment: In what format do you have these?  Do you have something like $h=0, $m=33 for the first one?  Or a string "0:33"?

Comment: a string, exactly as show above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this code a shot:

```
function getTotalDuration ($durations) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($durations as $duration) {
        $duration = explode(':',$duration);
        $total += $duration[0] * 60;
        $total += $duration[1];
    }
    $mins = $total / 60;
    $secs = $total % 60;
    return $mins.':'.$secs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added a couple things to pretty up the output, as shown in my edited question above.

Answer (score 2):

This stores the result in `$seconds`:

```
$seconds = 0;
foreach ($times as $time):
  list($m,$s) = explode(':',$time);  
  $seconds += $s + 60*$m;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert all times to seconds, add them as integers, convert the sum back to minutes and seconds?